# How can I access the particular tkinter StringVar that triggers a trace callback?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to use a trace callback to validate inputs to a set of combo boxes but the arguments I get in the callback are just a string representation of the internal name.  Is there a way to get a reference to the actual variable triggering the trace callback or a way to get at the variable using the internal name like PY_VAR1?

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk


def validate(self, *args):
    print(self)
    print(self.get())

master = Tk()

cb1_var = StringVar()
cb2_var = StringVar()
cb1_var.trace('w', validate)
cb2_var.trace('w', validate)

cb1 = ttk.Combobox(master, textvariable=cb1_var)
cb2 = ttk.Combobox(master, textvariable=cb2_var)

cb1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NW')
cb2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='NW')

mainloop()
```

Fails on trying to call self.get() since self is just that string representation, not the actual StringVar.  I don't want to have a specific callback for each StringVar since the actual interface has around 30 boxes I all want validated by the same criteria.

Comment: Why not use collection types if you have around 30 comboboxes & textvariables?

Comment: Did you do any research before askng? I feel like I’ve answered a similar question in the past week or two.

Comment: Yes.  Sorry I didn't find your answer.  I came across a post explaining the argument given to trace "is the internal variable name. More-or-less useless in a tkinter context, but extremely useful for the underlying tcl interpreter." but it seemed like I should be able to use it to get at the actual StringVar which is why I asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply pass the arguments you want by making use of `lambda` statement for anonymous functions. Replace:

```
def validate(self, *args):
    print(self)
    print(self.get())

...

cb1_var.trace('w', validate)
cb2_var.trace('w', validate)
```

with:

```
def validate(var):
    print(var)
    print(var.get())

...

cb1_var.trace('w', lambda *_, var=cb1_var: validate(var))
cb2_var.trace('w', lambda *_, var=cb2_var: validate(var))
```

---

If you use multiple objects that are related, simply use collection types. For the example in the question, I see a `list` should be a good fit.

See the example below:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk


def upon_var_change(var):
    print(var.get())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    cbs = list()
    for i in range(3):
        cbs.append(ttk.Combobox(root))
        cbs[i].var = tk.StringVar()
        cbs[i].var.trace_add('write', lambda *_,
                                        var=cbs[i].var:upon_var_change(var))
        cbs[i]['textvariable'] = cbs[i].var
        cbs[i].grid(row=i // 2, column=i % 2, sticky='nw')
    tk.mainloop()
```

---

If such is required you could identify the Variable class from its internal reference as well:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk


def upon_var_change(var_name):
    value = root.tk.globalgetvar(var_name)
    print(var_name, value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    cbs = list()
    for i in range(3):
        cbs.append(ttk.Combobox(root))
        cbs[i].var = tk.StringVar()
        cbs[i].var.trace_add('write', lambda var_name,
                                                *_: upon_var_change(var_name))
        cbs[i]['textvariable'] = cbs[i].var
        cbs[i].grid(row=i // 2, column=i % 2, sticky='nw')
    tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: I get an invalid syntax error at the  var=cbs[i].var assignment.  I'll try fiddling around with the lambda functions though, seems like the way to go.  I am working in Python 2.7 in case it's a 2 vs. 3 syntax issue.

Comment: @pwpropipe What's the error exactly? The order which var is declared matters.

Comment: `File "test.py", line 19
    cbs[i].var.trace_add('write', lambda *_, var=cbs[i].var:upon_var_change(var))
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`  
The ^ is pointing at the r in var=csb[i]

Comment: @pwpropipe I'd check the line above and below that, as it works for me.

Comment: The bit `root.tk.globalgetvar(var_name)` was exactly the piece I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: @pwpropipe Even though that works I'm skeptic that it is a good practice.

Comment: You deserve a snickers bar! Thank you kind sir!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, gut I found a way to use the internal variable name. Modify your `validate` function like this:

```
def validate(self, *args):
    var_name = args[0]
    var = IntVar(name=var_name)
    print(var.get())

master = Tk()

cb1_var = StringVar()
cb2_var = StringVar()
cb1_var.trace('w', validate)
cb2_var.trace('w', validate)
```