# How to pass string var in callback function using trace() in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new with python and trying to create two entry widgets to evaluate the data as soon as the user typed in the entry box. How to pass the string `var` into a function callback so that it will return exactly which entry box has changed. Now the callback function just returns the first entry box (`entry1`).

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import StringVar

main_wd = tkinter.Tk()
my_var1 = StringVar()
my_var2 = StringVar()

def my_callback(var):
    print("Traced variables {}".format(var.get())

my_var1.trace('write', my_callback(my_var1))
my_var2.trace('write', my_callback(my_var2))
entry1 = tkinter.Entry(main_wd, textvariable = my_var1).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
entry2 = tkinter.Entry(main_wd, textvariable = my_var2).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

main_wd.mainloop()
```

Comment: You forgot to close `)` at line 9

Comment: `my_var1.trace('write', my_callback(my_var1))` should be `my_var1.trace('w', my_callback(my_var1))` same with other one too. But this alone wont fix the issue. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48778189/how-can-i-access-the-particular-tkinter-stringvar-that-triggers-a-trace-callback)

Comment: Thanks for your response. But still the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To being in with, the usage of `trace` is wrong, meaning, the positional argument passed is wrong, it has to be `'w'` instead of `'write'`. Then next your calling the function when you use `()`, so you need to use `lambda` for that. So you `trace` would be like:

```
my_var1.trace('w', lambda *_,var=my_var1: my_callback(*_,var=var)) #*_ are the other arguments, like varname,value,mode ?
my_var2.trace('w', lambda *_,var=my_var2: my_callback(*_,var=var))
```

Then your function would be like:

```
def my_callback(*args,var):
    print("Traced variables {}".format(var.get()))
```

**TIP:**
Its better for `entry1` and `entry2` to not be `None`, so say:

```
entry1 = tkinter.Entry(main_wd, textvariable = my_var1)
entry1.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

entry2 = tkinter.Entry(main_wd, textvariable = my_var2)
entry2.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
```

When saying `pack()` on same line as the declaration, it will return what the last method returns. In this case, `pack()` returns `None`. So to make those entry widgets reusable, `pack()` them on separate line. Same applies to `grid()` and `place()`.

Final Code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import StringVar

main_wd = tkinter.Tk()
my_var1 = StringVar()
my_var2 = StringVar()

def my_callback(*args,var):
    print("Traced variables {}".format(var.get()))
    
my_var1.trace('w', lambda *_,var=my_var1: my_callback(*_,var=var))
my_var2.trace('w', lambda *_,var=my_var2: my_callback(*_,var=var))

entry1 = tkinter.Entry(main_wd, textvariable = my_var1)
entry1.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

entry2 = tkinter.Entry(main_wd, textvariable = my_var2)
entry2.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

main_wd.mainloop()
```

Comment: I got invalid syntax at my_var1.trace('w', lambda *_,var=my_var1: my_callback(*_,var=var))

Comment: @VanN You forgot the `*` I put there, but it shouldnt give any invalid syntax error unless you forgot a `)` or something. Try copy pasting and running the entire code in my updated answer.

Comment: @VanN  ~ Would appreciate marking this as the correct answer. Click [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to see how to mark as the answer.

Comment: So I got another problem that needs to be solved. Let say I have 4 entry boxes and user types the data in. I use the trace function to evaluate the data is valid or not. This is solved. I bind the entry box with <Tab> key and I want after entry1 is filled and user press Tab key to move to the next box the data in entry1 will be checked against min and max those are set specifically for entry boxes. If all pass then the data will be sent to the database. How to determine that the data after Tab key is pressed is belong to which entry box cause user after press tab can go back to edit the data.

Comment: @VanN You will get better answer, if you post an answer, because its pretty hard to explain and understand in the comments